# Dataflow SDK 2.7.0 while attaching a setup 2.10.0

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sdk, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to run a dataflow job, have the following setup.py file:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
              name='Some-Name',
              version='0.0.1',
              install_requires=[
                  'apache-beam==2.10.0',
                  'tensorflow-transform==0.12.0'
                  ],
              packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
              )
```

but when I submit the job to GCP, the SDK shows as 2.7.0 and the job won't run. It will stop after 1 hour with the following error:

Workflow failed. Causes: The Dataflow job appears to be stuck because no worker activity has been seen in the last 1h.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by updating the `tensorflow-transform` and apache-beam in my local virtual environment where I was submitting the dataflow job from. Once I updated my local apache-beam and `tensorflow-transform` and `tensorflow`, it seems to work. I'm not sure why since the `setup.py` stated the versions of the packages.